# Geometric (Trigonometric) inequality $\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{3abc}\leq1+\frac{4R}{r}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, contest-math, geometric-inequalities, sum-of-squares-method

How can one prove/disprove that $\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{3abc}\leq1+\frac{4R}{r}$ where $R$ and $r$ denote the usual circum and inradii respectively.

I know that $R=\frac{abc}{4\Delta}$ and $r=\frac{\Delta}{s}$, where $\Delta$ denotes area of triangle, and $s$ the semi perimeter. Any ideas. Thanks beforehand.

This is problem J392 from the [Problem column](https://www.awesomemath.org/wp-pdf-files/math-reflections/mr-2016-06/mr_6_2016_problems_1.pdf) of [Mathematical Reflections](https://www.awesomemath.org/mathematical-reflections/) - Issue 6 2016.

Comment: https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/b-c-pi-prove-that-identity-true-sin-sin-b-sin-c-154655 and  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Exradius.htmll

Comment: @labbhattacharjee how does that help here?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee may be exradius has some connection, but sorry, i am unable to see it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can prove that $$\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{3abc}\leq1+\frac{4R}{r}$$
Indeed, we need to prove that
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{3abc}\leq1+\frac{\frac{abc}{S}}{\frac{2S}{a+b+c}}$$ or
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{3abc}\leq1+\frac{8abc(a+b+c)}{16S^2}$$ or
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{3abc}\leq1+\frac{8abc}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b-c)}$$ or
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{3abc}\leq\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(-a^3+a^2b+a^2c+2abc)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b-c)}$$ or
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{3abc}\leq\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(-a^3+abc+a^2b+a^2c+abc)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b-c)}$$
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3abc}\leq\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(-a^2+ab+ab)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b-c)}$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}a\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)\leq3\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2c-a^3bc)$$ or
$$2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^4b+a^4c-a^3b^2-a^3c^2-2a^3bc+2a^2b^2c)+\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^5-a^4b-a^4c+a^3bc)\geq0,$$ for which it's enough to prove that
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2(ab(a+b)-abc)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2ab(a+b-c)\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: sorry for the wrong question, please see the modified post.

Comment: how do you explain from  the sixth to seventh step above?

Comment: @vidyarthi $\sum\limits_{cyc}a\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)\leq3\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2c-a^3bc)$ or $\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^3b^2+2a^3c^2+2a^2b^2c-a^5-a^4b-a^4c)\leq\sum\limits_{cyc}(6a^2b^2c-3a^3bc)$ or $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^5+a^4b+a^4c-2a^3b^2-2a^3c^2+4a^2b^2c-3a^3bc)$ and we get a seventh step.